# Ctrl left/right/delete and alt up/down stopped working in one eclipse tab

Tags: eclipse

In one of my tabs (it's popped out) I can no longer use any of these key combinations: Ctrl + left/right/backspace/delete or Alt + up/down. There may be others but these are what I use commonly.

It's incredibly annoying and slows me down a lot. My other popped out windows still work and even other tabs, in the window with the non-working tab, will still work.

I don't understand how I changed this or how to change it back.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the mode of that one window? (is it editing a different type of file?)

Comment: @BRPocock What does mode mean, how do I find out? and no they're all the same file types (.java)

Comment: I was wondering if perhaps one were Java source, another XML, &c.